# Is there such a thing as a smaller vent cap than the 4"

Tags: bathroom

I need a vent cap to fit without touching an adjacent vent pipe i.e.vent cap cover needs to be < 4 1/2 " ( possibly might work <5" ) to fit into opening to exhaust air outside from a bathroom.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Perhaps a photo of the vent where it exits the house would help.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an off-set vent cap like this: [Sears.com offset vent](https://m.sears.com/builder-s-best-vent-periscope-0-to-5-inches/p-02649901000P)

Or extend and vent to the side: [Whirlpool 5-in x 4-in Galvanized Steel Round Duct Elbow](https://www.lowes.com/pd/whirlpool-5-in-x-4-in-galvanized-steel-round-duct-elbow/3353516)

Answer (score 0):

3" is a less-common but still available size.
Here's a few options in 3"

- A [dryer vent cap][1]
- A [misc vent][2] cap
- [Another][3]

Caution if constricting a 4" fan outlet to a 3" vent, the flow restriction can cause the fan to encounter too much resistance and burn up.
[1]: https://seiho.com/product/cfx/cfx.html
[2]: https://seiho.com/product/sfx/sfx.html
[3]: https://seiho.com/product/kx/kx.html